# Parallel and separate file reading using two methods (C#)

Tags: c#, .net

There are 2 methods: bubble sort and shaker sort. These methods read 1 file, which contains a line with numbers separated by spaces. It is necessary to make sure that one method reads, for example, 20 numbers, and another method reads, for example, the next 15 numbers, and each one works with their own numbers and makes a general conclusion, where it will be clear what number a certain method worked on. Thank you

I tried using async/await, ParallelFor/ParallelForEach. But it all turned out to be meaningless.
Here is my code at the moment:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace start_bubble
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static Thread sortBubble, sortShaker;

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nМассив в файле:");
            string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Kadir/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/start_bubble/number.txt");
            int[] boss = fileContent.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", boss));

            sortBubble = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Bubble(boss);
            });
            sortShaker = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Shaker(boss);
            });

            sortBubble.Name = "BUBBLE";
            sortShaker.Name = "SHAKER";

            sortBubble.Start();
            sortShaker.Start();

            sortBubble.Join();
            sortShaker.Join();
            
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Bubble(int[] sBubble)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sBubble.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < sBubble.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (sBubble[i] > sBubble[j])
                    {
                        int T = sBubble[i];
                        sBubble[i] = sBubble[j];
                        sBubble[j] = T;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", "B - [", i, "]: ", sBubble[i]));
            }
        }

        static void Shaker(int[] sShaker)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sShaker.Length; i++)
            {
                //left to right
                for (int j = i; j < sShaker.Length - i - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (sShaker[j] > sShaker[j + 1])
                    {
                        int temp = sShaker[j];
                        sShaker[j] = sShaker[j + 1];
                        sShaker[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }

                //right to left
                for (int j = sShaker.Length - i - 1; j > i; j--)
                {
                    if (sShaker[j - 1] > sShaker[j])
                    {
                        int temp = sShaker[j - 1];
                        sShaker[j - 1] = sShaker[j];
                        sShaker[j] = temp;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", "S - [", i, "]: ", sShaker[i]));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to split the numbers in sequential blocks you can use the [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) feature of C#, you can simply write:

```
int[] boss = fileContent.Split().Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
Bubble(boss[0..20]);
Shaker(boss[20..35]);
```

Of course, you can still call these methods by using threads.

However, if the methods can take the numbers in an interleaved manner from the threads, I would use [Thread-safe collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/). E.g.:

```cs
IEnumerable<int> boss = fileContent.Split().Select(Int32.Parse);
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>(boss);
var sortBubble = new Thread(() =>
{
    Bubble(queue);
});
var sortShaker = new Thread(() =>
{
    Shaker(queue);
});
... and so on ...
```

I tested sharing the numbers without the actual sorting with these methods:

```cs
static void Bubble(ConcurrentQueue<int> queue)
{
    var list = new List<int>(20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Thread.Sleep(Random.Shared.Next(100));
        if (queue.TryDequeue(out var n)) {
            list.Add(n);
        };
    }
    // Sorting list would go here...
    Console.WriteLine("Bubble: " + String.Join(", ", list));
}

static void Shaker(ConcurrentQueue<int> queue)
{
    var list = new List<int>(15);
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        Thread.Sleep(Random.Shared.Next(100));
        if (queue.TryDequeue(out var n)) {
            list.Add(n);
        };
    }
    // Sorting list would go here...
    Console.WriteLine("Shaker: " + String.Join(", ", list));
}
```

To give time for task switching I added a `Thread.Sleep` with a random number of milliseconds. Otherwise the methods will be too fast and one method will take all its numbers in a contiguous way and the other one all the remaining numbers.

With an input of

```cs
string fileContent = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37";
```

I get an output of

```
Shaker: 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 13, 14, 16, 20, 23, 25, 27, 28, 29
Bubble: 2, 4, 7, 9, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 24, 26, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35
```

Comment: excuse me, but can you show how to add sorting methods to these methods? I'm racking my brains, but it doesn't work.

Comment: In my first example with indexes and ranges your sorting method would remain unchanged (I didn't test your sorting algorithms, so). In the other example I show only the multi-threaded numbers gathering part. Sorting would simply follow the gathering (just before the Console.WriteLine).